# Sum in the reciprocal lattice

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals

I have to use this property but I don't understand at all the deduction, so I was wondering if someone could help me.

We have a crystal lattice with vectors to each atom from one of them $R_j$, and we have the next sum:

$$F_\alpha(\vec r)=\sum_je^{-\alpha(\vec r-\vec R_j)^2/a^2}$$
Now we express $F_\alpha(r)$ through its Fourier transform:

$$F_\alpha(\vec r)=\frac{1}{V}\sum_l \bar F_\alpha(k_l)e^{i\vec k_l\cdot\vec r}$$

where $\bar\cdot$ denotes the Fourier transform and $k_l$ are the vectors of the reciprocal lattice.

Now they say that in the thermodinamical limit we can write

$$\frac{1}{V}\bar F_\alpha(k_l)=\rho\int d^3\vec r e^{-\alpha r^2/a^2}e^{-i\vec k_l\cdot\vec r}=\rho a^3\left(\frac{\pi}{\alpha}\right)^{3/2}e^{-k_l^2a^2/4\alpha}$$

I don't understand at all how that's done. $\rho$ is the inverse volume and $a$ is the lattice parameter so $\rho a^3$ is the number of atoms per unit cell.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Generalizations

Comment: It's a 3D integral in spherical polar coordinates so $d^3\vec r = r^2\sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi$